# JSP file to be recalled with user's data when an analysis fails

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2

I have an application running in Tomcat using the Struts 2 framework.  It works very well but I have a basic question about the flow of control.

My struts.xml file contains many "action" tags which have name, method and class parameters.  The included "result" tag determines where control goes when the specified method completes its work.  All of this makes sense and works well.

Many of my JSP files include an HTML "form" tag that calls one of my actions when the form is submitted.  The thing I don't know is how to return to the calling JSP when an analysis performed in the method fails.

Here is a summary of what I would like to do.

(1) user puts "input" values in form and clicks submit.

(2) the method called by the action retrieves the form data and performs an analysis.

(3) when a criteria in the analysis fails, the previous JSP file reappears on the user's screen with the same input data filled in, and it has a dialog box explaining the problem.

The one thing I don't know how to do is have the method trigger a restore of the JSP file with all of the user's values still inside the form fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable struts 2 to validate input of user, you have to define a validate method in your action class. For example.

```
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport{

    public void validate(){
        if(!firstName.equals("JimB77")){
            //addFieldError(firstName, "first name is not equal to JimB77");    
            addActionError("You have an error on your inputs..");
        }
    }

    public String performAnalysis(){
        System.out.println("perform analysis logic..");
        return SUCCESS;
    }


    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    //getters and setters

}
```

validate() method will validate all request that will be called in this class, to validate a specific method you just have to add validate + your method name. So we will change the validate() to validatePerformAnalysis().

```
public void validatePerformAnalysis(){
        if(!firstName.equals("JimB77")){
            //addFieldError(firstName, "first name is not equal to JimB77");    
            addActionError("You have an error on your inputs..");
        }
    }
```

Notice the addActionError and addFieldError, you should define addFieldError if you want to a specific fields or input to have an error. For now what I used is addActionError which used for general error messages.

> The one thing I don't know how to do is have the method trigger a
>   restore of the JSP file with all of the user's values still inside the
>   form fields.

Struts 2 handle it for you. To retain the value of your inputs, you just have to define

```
<result name="input">/pages/user.jsp</result>
```

So for example, we have an action like :

```
<action name="performAnalysis" class="x.y.z.action.UserAction" method="performAnalysis">
            <result name="success">pages/user.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/pages/user.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

In this way when validation fails and struts 2 returns input like in above, the struts 2 will redisplay user.jsp and retain all the values you've input. Also it will add the error message that we define in addActionError method.

Now to display the error msg. We could have something like this.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>

<script>
var error="";
function showDialog(msg){
        alert(msg);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<s:form action="/performAnalysis" >

    <s:textfield name="firstName" />
    <s:textfield name="lastName" />
    <s:submit value="Submit" />

</s:form>
   <s:if test="hasActionErrors()">
      <s:iterator var="error" value="actionErrors"> //display all actionErrors similar to <s:actionerror />
        <script>
              error += "<s:property value='#error' />";
            </script> 
      </s:iterator>
      <script>
        showDialog(error);
      </script>
   </s:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough answer.  It's going to take me a little while to absorb all of this.  Thanks again!

Comment: I have spent a great deal of time studying your answer and have successfully implemented all of these steps.  Everything works perfectly except for one thing --> the fields in the JSP are blank when the page comes back with error messages displayed.  I did add an "input" result in the struts.xml file but the user's rejected input values are not retained in the JSP.

Comment: As I test, this works perfectly. Make sure you have same field with input in html and fields in action class. Can you post your code?

Comment: I finally got it to work!  My mistake was I used HTML's "input" tag for user data instead of "s:textfield."  THANK YOU!  I've always struggled to understand Validation in Struts 2 and your clear explanation with simple examples has allowed me to make huge progress in that endeavor.  Thanks again for taking the time to do this for me.